# Column Logic in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, bigdata, sql-server-2014

First time poster here! I would like peoples opinions here. I am collecting daily stock data for the past 10yrs (so approximately 2500 rows of data which is not significant), however I have over 200 stocks (will grow to 1000 over time possibly) with about 30 individual fields per stock. So we are talking about a table that has originally 6000 columns that grows to have over 30000 columns one day, but more appropriately perhaps only 6000-10000 columns to start with. I recognise that an SQL database may not be the best approach, there are many 'big data' programs like mongodb, hadoop etc however I never used them (only SQL)

Can anyone shed some light on the best way to store this in SQL. I know each table is limited to 1024 columns, do people suggest I break this into possibly 10+ separate tables? I'm interested in the effects this has on performance?

Note that each stock and its features will be mutually exclusive of all other stocks in the database.

Looking forward to opinions

Comment: **what ?  (>_<)** so much columns, anyway you can't just outdate the use of mysql and other databases because they are working perfectly till now ,Yes you can have BigData tools,however in my opinion you need to optimize your problem,Think of splitting your problem in pieces,1024 (or do't know the exact value,but i know whatever it is,it is enough) columns are enough,but you need to design a pattern to save the data.

Comment: In a well defined SQL schema the number of columns don't grow, only the number of rows. If by any way your number of columns is growing you got a serious lack of normalization problem or you are not using a relational dbms at all

Comment: You should read something about relational database design. Look for database normalization - good start would be here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization . But to simplify it: when you see sql table with more than, let's say 10 columns, your database model is probably flawed. It's not a hard value, sometimes more colums are really needed, but I'm 100% sure, your problem does not call for 30000 column table. Read the wiki article, please.

Comment: First decide if you're using MySQL or SQL Server. (Then remove non-valid tag.)

Comment: This question is stereotypical of people's lack of understanding of relational data models to favor _cool_ and _trendy_ NoSQL tools. Do yourself a favor, learn relational data models. And even if you don't use it for this application, you'll find that there's already a tool for >90% of the problems you'll ever face.

Comment: Thankyou for the feedback. I've never used databases in the capacity that some here have. I'm still very much learning. I clearly missed some of the logic but I understand exactly what I must do now I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you have so many different columns.  You should have one row per stock per time unit.  I would envision a structure with a few dozen columns:

- Stock Identifier
- Date (or date/time)
- 30 or so measures per stock

You seem to want to store things in columns that should be in rows.

This is a reasonably sized data set, but it is probably just a few million rows and a few gigabytes.  Databases support much larger sets of data.

Answer (score 0):

So many columns is a design smell.

However, MySQL supports only up to 4096 columns in a table. An excerpt from the documentation of [`CREATE TABLE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

> There is a hard limit of 4096 columns per table, but the effective maximum may be less for a given table and depends on the factors discussed in Section D.10.4, [“Limits on Table Column Count and Row Size”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html).